# git svn clone not picking up deletes

Tags: git, svn, clone

I am having an issue exporting some files from an svn repo to a new git repo.  I'm grabbing a set of files and have passed in the few paths that they have had over time as my --include-paths argument.

It's picking up the additions of the files, but not the deletes when they were moved.  The end repo has the files in the old and new path.

Another odd part is that there was an directory in the middle there at one point in time.  Those additions and deletes were recorded and the intermediary directory is empty in resulting repo

`git svn clone svn+ssh://my/repo/trunk --include-paths="^(src/com/test/initial|src/com/test/middle/[\w]*\.java|src/com/test/latest/[\w]*\.java)"`

If I do not include the --include-paths arg everything is correct.  Any idea why the move from initial to middle directories is only doing the add part of the commit?

Comment: A little more information.... I changed my regex to just be one of the file names that have remained constant with the same result.  One of the things I noticed is the move of the file from middle to latest also had some changes to file content, and the move from initial to middle was just a move operation with an add and a delete.